# Comparing Dates with different formats in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to compare 2 dates that have 2 different formats in Javascript.

The date from my database is `2013-04-21` (date1) and the date in the array prints out in the following format in my Chrome debugger: `Sun Apr 21 2013 15:37:05 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` (date2)

I'd like to compare only the date part and leave out the time: `date1 == date2` is true.

How would I go about formatting the dates so I'd be able to compare them?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
y = date2.getFullYear();
m = date2.getMonth()+1;
m = (m<10)? ('0'+m) : m;
d = date2.getDate();
d2 = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;

if (date1 == d2) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date1.toISOString().split("T")[0] == date2.toISOString().split("T")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to go a little deeper here: we have to distinguishe between Strings storing date, and the Date object which can store dates and do computation with dates.

From your description i guess that date1 is acutally a string "2013-04-21" while date2 is already a Date object.

You could convert date1 to a date object:

```
date1AsObject = new Date("2013-04-21");
```

Then you could compute the difference between them:

```
diff = date2 - date1AsObject
```

the result will be in milliseconds.

or you could convert date2 to a string like 
Crayon Violent suggested:

```
y = date2.getFullYear();
m = date2.getMonth()+1;
d = date2.getDate();
date2AsString = y+'-'+m+'-'+d;
```

then you can compare the two strings.